# which preposition must be used "through" or "by"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

In sentences :

1. > We can derive a closed-form expression **through** integration of X.
2. > The closed-form expression can be derived **by** integration of X.
3. > We can derive the optimal solution **through** optimization of X.
4. > The optimal solution can be derived **by** optimization of X.

Given to [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25459/what-general-rules-govern-the-usage-of-by-versus-through), we are recommended that to use "through" when we have a process ( i.e., an start point + a procedure and a final result). Also, we should use "by" when we want to focus on method.

---

**Google Results:**

"through integration" = 478 k

"by integration" = 710 k

"through optimization" = 206 k

"by optimization" = 320 k

---

Now the question is, in above context ( Mathematics ) which one we should use? We can infer both a method and a process. ( the integration can be complex and you might need to do some complex calculations in multiple stages). However, google demonstrates the usage of "by" is more frequent.

---

PS : I think if we use **through**, we say the significant part of the following is the procedure. However, when we use **by**, we should expect the reader focusing on the used tool. In fact, we induct the procedure is unimportant and superficial. Am I right ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've found the difference between the two.

If some process is important and it's quite an undertaking, even an ordeal, then '*through*' is more appropriate.  "*Better shape lies through vigorous exercise.*"

If the same process is less important in itself, and perhaps it doesn't take up so much resources (computational, time, money, people), then '*by*' seems better.

Comment: Thanks Mr Bazarov. I was eager to know if it really conveys such information in native people ?

Comment: Let's hope native people will share their views too.